C# LinQ: Filter object[] with elements containing a string (or part of it) from a string[]
I have a "Licenses" query which returns a Licenses[] object as follows:
var licenses = await _licenseRepository.SearchAsync(ct); //=> CT = CancellationToken

and a request filter which allows to filer by Id or Name:
public sealed record Filter(LicenseTypeValues[] Id, string[] Name);

So I should be able to pass a string[] as "Name" filter (for example) and I should return every License which name contains any of the names in the string[] -or part of them-.
Let's consider the following return from the licenses query with no filter:
{
    "count": 5,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 15005,
            "name": "Windows 2012",
            "maxCpu": null,
            "parentId": 15032,
            "created": "2021-02-16T08:17:45Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 15027,
            "name": "Windows 2016",
            "maxCpu": null,
            "parentId": 15032,
            "created": "2021-02-16T08:17:45Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 15030,
            "name": "Windows 2022",
            "maxCpu": null,
            "parentId": 15032,
            "created": "2021-08-11T10:29:36Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 15032,
            "name": "Ubuntu 23",
            "maxCpu": null,
            "parentId": 15,
            "created": "2023-05-22T14:56:11.93Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 15032,
            "name": "Ubuntu 24",
            "maxCpu": null,
            "parentId": 15,
            "created": "2023-05-22T14:56:11.93Z"
        }
    ]
}

Then, if I pass a filter like the following:
["Windows 201", "Ubuntu 23"]

the response should be:
{
    "count": 3,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 15005,
            "name": "Windows 2012",
            "maxCpu": null,
            "parentId": 15032,
            "created": "2021-02-16T08:17:45Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 15027,
            "name": "Windows 2016",
            "maxCpu": null,
            "parentId": 15032,
            "created": "2021-02-16T08:17:45Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 15032,
            "name": "Ubuntu 23",
            "maxCpu": null,
            "parentId": 15,
            "created": "2023-05-22T14:56:11.93Z"
        }
    ]
}

My first attempt using just a simple LinQ with a lambda expression was:
var licenses = await _repository.FindAll().Where(x => filter.Name.Contains(x.Name)).ToArrayAsync();

The problem with this query is that only works with exact matches (ex: "Windows 2019" or "Ubuntu 23"), but not partial matches.
Of course I could just iterate with a foreach loop and filter every element one by one, but I'd like to find a more elegant solution using LinQ, if possible.
Any suggestions?
Edit 1: Explanation of the problem described above.
What I'm trying to say with "my example query only works with exact matches" is that if I search, for example, ["Windows 2016"], or, another example, ["Windows 2012", "Ubuntu 23"] it will work, but with ["Windows 20"] or ["Ubunbtu", "Windows"] won't, because the match is not exact, and this is what my example does, just works with exact matches, so it works partially.

Which ORM and version? Which database provider?

I don't understand what you mean by "The problem with this query is that only works with exact matches (ex: "Windows 2019" or "Ubuntu 23"), but not partial matches." It appears that your code and your text in this sentence and your example in the sentence are all incongruent with each other.

Hello @Enigmativity, thanks for your comments, and please see my edit for further explanations about the problem with my example query.

@DiegoPerez you didn't provide any additional information. What database are you using and what ORM? LINQ doesn't get executed by itself, it must be translated to SQL. If you use EF or NHibernate, that single-entity "repository" is a big design bug, because ORMs are higher level abstractions than CRUD classes. It also means that unless FindAll() just returns a DbSet, the query itself will be affected by whatever that method does

@DiegoPerez databases aren't implementation details.  Searching in the middle of a string is the slowest way possible as it can't use any indexes and requires a full table scan. Searching for words though can use full-text search indexes and different SQL syntax. Which means you need a different LINQ query too. The SQL Server LINQ provider, NpgSql for PostgreSQL and Pomelo for MySQL all offer FTS functions, like Contains/FreeText for SQL Server, Match for MySQL, vector matches for PostgreSQL. Which database are you using?

@DiegoPerez on the other hand, Windows 20 doesn't require contains. It can use BeginsWith, which gets translated to title LIKE 'Windows 20% and that can use normal indexes because it's essentially a range search, title >='Windows 20' and title <'Windows 21'

Thanks 4 your input @Panagiotis Kanavos, I'm migrating an existing API from .Net 5 to .Net 8, and I've just checked how the filter currently works to realize it not only works with Begin for the matches, if you enter "indows", it will consider Windows whatever as a valid response, or -for example- if you use "ed" it would also include "Red Hat" in the results. For the moment the solution given below works just fine, and as licenses are not that much, speed is not a problem here. Anyway, as I'm always looking for the best way to do things, if you think of a better approach, I'd like 2 know it.

What you ask if fuzzy matching, which just isn't available in most relational databases and SQL Server in particular. You'll end up searching the entire table every time. Such searches can be accelerated by search engines like Elastic or trigram indexes in PostgreSQL - essentially, PostgreSQL breaks the text into 3-character and creates an index showing in which rows they're found. In SQL Server you'd have to create your own trigram solution

There are articles like this one that show how to use trigrams in SQL Server. You do need extra space but data compression can help a lot here. You'll have to create either a scheduled job or triggers to maintain the trigram tables though.

I think using .Any() is helpful here.
var licenses = await _repository.FindAll().Where(x => filter.Name.Any(f => x.Name.Contains(f)).ToArrayAsync();

Since filter.Name is also a list, it can use LINQ expressions. Also, f should now be contained in x.Name.
Hope that helps!

Even if this could be translated to SQL, it would be very, very slow.

Hello @TBold, and thanks for your time. I've tried your solution and it worked as expected. Great! :)
